# How can I get this for loop to skip over meetings where there is no attendee and no external attendee based on domain.com?

Tags: python, loops, try-catch

I am looking to print out the calendar event name and external email based on the criteria below. Currently the for loop works and I get desired results until I hit a meeting where there were no attendees.

```
for calendar_id in me:
        count = 0
        eventsResult = service.events().list(
            calendarId=calendar_id,
            timeMax=now,
            timeMin=end_date).execute()

        events = service.events().list(calendarId=calendar_id).execute()
        events = events.get('items', [])


        for event in events:
            start = event['start'].get('dateTime')

            for attendees in event['attendees']:
                atte = attendees.get('email')
                try:
                    attid = event.get(attendees)
                    if "domain.com" not in atte:
                        print('\n' + event['summary'] + " " + "(Calendar - " + calendar_id + ")")
                        print(attendees['email'])
                    else:
                        continue
                except:
                    pass
```

Comment: What is actually returned in cases of "No Attendees"? Is it an empty collection or something else?

Comment: What happens when you hit a meeting where there were no attendees?

Comment: ```Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "Calendar_Trial.py", line 119, in <module>
    main()
  File "Calendar_Trial.py", line 99, in main
    for attendees in event['attendees']:
KeyError: 'attendees'```

This is the return I get. That is what I can't seem to figure out. The return of "attendees" when there are none.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the get method of dict to check if there are attendees in an event with the default of empty list

```
for attendees in event.get('attendees', []):
```

or you can check

```
if 'attendees' in event.keys():
    for attendees in event['attendees']:
```

In case, there are no attendees then the for loop of events will continue to the next event.

Comment: I tried that. Didn't seem to help. Still getting stuck with the above error in the for loop

Comment: I've edited the answer you can check if that helped.

Comment: I think that's doing the trick, but now it seems to fail farther up in the for loop.

```File "Calendar_Trial.py", line 118, in <module>
    main()
  File "Calendar_Trial.py", line 87, in main
    start = event['start'].get('dateTime')
KeyError: 'start'```

Comment: Now you have a separate question, although the solution might be to apply the same technique again. You should try looking at the `event` data in cases that make the code fail, so that you can scan for any irregularities. Also, try reading the documentation again to see if it's explained when and why the data is like this.

Comment: Its not really a separate question though. The loop is still failing on meetings without attendees.

Comment: So you can do if 'start' in event.keys(): or event['start'].get('dateTime') if 'start' in event.keys() else None